# Pass same module interface from one file to another

Tags: typescript

I have these two files:

core.ts

```
import * as express from "express";
namespace Routes {
    interface pageParams {
        req: express.Request,
        res: express.Response,
        next: express.NextFunction 
    };
}
```

login.ts

```
/// <reference path="core.ts"/>
namespace Routes {
    export class index {
        public index(params: pageParams) {
            params.res.render('index');
        }
    }
}
```

login.ts could not see the pageParams' interface. What am I missing?
Thank you.

Comment: try exporting pageParams

Comment: @iberbeu did that, it didn't work.

Comment: `export interface pageParams` this works for me in typescript-plaground. It should work for you too. It can also be that the reference is wrong